# ASP.NET MVC: Routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-routing

So I have this controller action:

```
public ActionResult Categories(int typecode)
{
  // code removed
}
```

this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(null,
  "{controller}/{action}/{typecode}",
  new { controller = "Search", action = "Categories", }
);
```

and this link to call the route:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ga", "Categories", "Search", new { typecode = 16860 }, null)
```

if I use this, my URL is: `http://localhost:50033/Search/Categories?typecode=16860`
but if I change all occurences of `typecode` to `id`, it works and I get this URL: `http://localhost:50033/Search/Categories/16860`

So with typecode my route doesn't work and with id it does. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I think I wasn't clear enough, but in my `Global.asax.cs` file I have this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute("TypeCode",
    "Search/Categories/{typecode}",
    new { controller = "Search", action = "Categories" }
  );
}
```

So that's only ONE route, than in my `SearchController` I have this `Categories` action:

```
public ActionResult Categories(int typecode)
{
  // Irrelevant code removed
}
```

So the parameter is exactly the same as the route parameter, then I have this link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ga", "Categories", "Search", new { typecode = 16860 }, null)
```

Also using exactly the route parameter, but still the generated link is: `http://localhost:50033/Search/Categories?typecode=16860` so that's not what I want.

Now, when i **replace** all typecode occurences, like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute("TypeCode",
    "Search/Categories/{id}",
    new { controller = "Search", action = "Categories" }
  );
}

public ActionResult Categories(int id)
{
  // irrelevant code removed
}

@Html.ActionLink("Ga", "Categories", "Search", new { id = 16860 }, null)
```

It works! so I **replaced** everything, there are no more routes, I just replaced the 3 `typecode` occurences with `id`.

Why is this? Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which url is it you want to have `/Categories?typecode={id}` or `/Categories/{id}`?

Comment: Take a look http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/02/asp-net-mvc-3-optional-parameter-routing-issue.aspx

Comment: @James I want `/Categories/{typecode}`

Comment: @FelipeOriani I am using MVC 4. This issue is only with 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. I will explain what went wrong for anyone who has the same issue.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 for this project, earlier I created some webshops with MVC 3. What I always did, was putting the routes in the `Global.asax.cs` file. Now, when I started my project, there was no `RegisterRoutes()` method, so I created one and put my routes in it. Just now I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173936/cant-find-route-name-in-route-collection) post and it says that MVC 4 registers its routes in `App_Data/RouteConfig.cs` I checked out that file, and saw the `RegisterRoutes()` method with one route, the default one with as optional parameter `id`.

So that is why it was only working with `id` as parameter, MVC 4 didn't even look at my route in `Global.asax.cs`, and just picked up the only route from `App_Data/RouteConfig.cs`.

I did put my route in the `App_Data/RouteConfig.cs` file and it works! Learned something again, and I'm glad it finally works. Also I want to say thanks to @James for helping me.

Comment: Makes sense because it most definitely wasn't picking up the default route. +1 for figuring it out :)

Comment: Just a note: that RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method is explicitly called from Global.asax Application_Start method. If you didn't want the default routes you could also remove/comment out that line or if you want to register any routes before the default one just do it before that call happens.

Comment: I know about that, already removed the default one ;). Thanks for caring anyway!

Answer (score 2):

> So with typecode my route doesn't work and with id it does. What am I doing wrong?

The problem is you no doubt still have the default route being mapped *before* your custom route i.e.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Which means anything that matches a url similar to "controller/action/id" will be parsed by the default route, not your custom one. The fact that this route does not recognise `typecode` as an expected parameter means it's treated as a query string parameter (hence `?typecode=`).

If you want to pick up the `typecode` be more specific with which controller you want to map it to and put this route *before* the default one i.e.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CategoryItem",
    "{controller}/Categories/{typecode}",
    new { controller = "Search", action = "Categories", typecode = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

This would constrain any urls which start like `controller/Categories/` to only accept a `typecode` and not an `id` - this should result in your URL forming as `Search/Categories/12345`. You could constraint this further by controller if you really wanted to (just replace `{controller}` with `Search` in the route).

However, I don't see any *real* benefits of doing this considering you don't actually show `typecode` in the URL anywhere. I could understand if you were looking to show the url as `Search/Categories?typecode=12345` as it's probably a bit more descriptive than `id`. Personally, I would leave your default route as is and change your action link to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Ga", "Categories", "Search", new { id = 16860 }, null)
```

It will give you the same result.

**Update**

Based on your update, the only thing I can think of is you aren't specifying a default value in the route so perhaps it's not picking the parameter correctly, try:

```
routes.MapRoute("TypeCode",
    "Search/Categories/{typecode}",
    new { controller = "Search", action = "Categories", typecode = "" }
);
```

Comment: That is not true, the route with `{typecode}` IS actually before the default one, it is the first route... and why not using id? because typecode is not the only code I'm gonna use, if this one works, I also need an `menucode` and an `partcode` and so on, so I just can't use id for all of them. So why is my route not working while it IS really the first route... even the only...

Comment: James please check my updated question, Thanks for your time. Appreciate it.