# Routing in RedirectToAction mvc5 with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I am having a ActionResult Method where in end i am having a return statement to 'Redirect.ToAction' with parameters. Which in turn the redirected method returns a view. Since it is having a parameter, the URL is not following my Route[] attribute which i have defined over the method. How it is possible?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit()
{
    ... some code
    return RedirectToRoute("ThankYou", new
    {
        controller = "Form",
        action = "ThankYou",
        rID = SessionValues.ID,
        cID = cID
    });
}

[Route("thankyoupage")]
public ActionResult ThankYou(int rID, int cID)
{
    return this.View("ThankYou", obj);
}
```

when i view is returned i am getting a URl like

```
https://localhost/form?id=21&cID=2.
```

I need like,

```
https://localhost/thankyoupage
```

Comment: You cannot achieve just `localhost/thankyoupage` - your passing 2 parameters (`rID and cID`) so that must appear as query string or route values

Comment: Your Submit and ThankYou methods are ok, you probably have as issue in your route. Read this and check out your route: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944355/redirecttoaction-and-redirecttoroute

Comment: And your title and question state `RedirectToAction` yet you code is `RedirectToRoute`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually RedirectToAction dint worked. So i tried with RedirectToRoute

Comment: @RicardoPontual My routing is like this
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );

Comment: @NithyaShree, Either way, you cannot have just `/thankyoupage` - your passing values for 2 parameters so they must appear in the url - how would the method know their values if they weren't :)

Comment: Yes i can agree your point. But i can achieve what i required when i go directly to the method, instead of redirecting from another method. I hope we can make it..