# Application_Error custom error handler in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, webforms, global-asax

I want to detect and redirect custom errors from Global.asax. It returns 200 ok or null. I am not sure how can i detect and redirect to errors automatically. I hope you guys have an idea.

**In Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
</system.webServer>
```

**In Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

                Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

                if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 200)
                {
                    errormessage = ex.Message;
                    Response.RedirectToRoute("error");
                }
                else if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 400)
                {
                    errormessage = ex.Message;
                   Response.RedirectToRoute("error");
                }
                else if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404)
                {
                    errormessage = ex.Message;
                    Response.RedirectToRoute("error");
                }
                else if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 500)
                {
                    errormessage = ex.Message;
                    Response.RedirectToRoute("error");
                }
                else
                {
                    errormessage = ex.Message;
                    Response.RedirectToRoute("error");
                }
    Server.ClearError();
}
```

Comment: i'd take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944355/redirecttoaction-and-redirecttoroute

Comment: I'm using webforms @PeterKarman

Comment: ah how about plain old Response.Redirect then? Something like Response.Redirect("/error.aspx"). Also, it seems like you don't need do the various checks you are doing as you are always redirecting to error. Just redirecting in the method should be sufficient

Comment: Thanks, i can handle error code '400' but i can't handle 404 not found.. do you have an idea why? @PeterKarman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

I found temporary solution for my problem. It's not the best but you may need it.

**In Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" /> // On or Off doesn't matter ISS 7 or newer version
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Auto">
     <clear/>
     <error statusCode="404" path="/notfound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
     </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

**In Global.asax**

```
HttpException httpexception = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException() as HttpException;
string ex_message = httpexception.InnerException;
// send or save errors here
Server.ClearError();
Response.Redirect("error");
```

**Note:** I didn't handle 404 error from codebehind, web.configuration helps about it.